# "const const T" in template

Tags: c++, templates, constants

The following code compiles and works on G++ 4.4.0 and MS VC2008 Express.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct A{
protected:
    T v;
public:
    const T get() const{
        return v;
    }

    A(T v_)
    :v(v_){
    }
};

class B: public A<const int*>{
public:
    void doSomething() const{
        const int* tmp = get();
        std::cout << *tmp << std::endl;
    }

    B(const int* p)
    :A<const int*>(p){
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int a = 134;
    B b(&a);
    const B& c = b;
    b.doSomething();
    c.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

However, as I understand it using `A<const int*>` should result in `const const int* A::get() const;`. And I'm pretty sure I haven't seen anything like that in real code. Is using template in such way "legal"?

If not, what are alternatives? In my code I need a template class that provides two "getter" methods (const/non-const), and can take a "const int*" as a type. Something like this:

```
template<typename T> struct A{
protected:
    T v;
public:
    const T get() const{
        return v;
    }

    T get(){
        return v;
    }

    A(T v_)
    :v(v_){
    }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have a "constant craving" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `T = const int *`, then `const T` is `const int * const`.

Comment: Okay, If I missed something like *that*, then I guess I need to take a break. Thank you for fast reply.

Comment: @SigTerm: ...and that's why I love to put `const` on the right... Adding `const` to `int const *` is `int const * const`, which is simple to reason about :)

Answer (score 4):

We can translate

```
const int *
```

into

```
int const *
```

A pointer to a constant int.
When you have T=int*, what you have with const T is:

```
int * const
```

Which means, a constant pointer to a int.

So in your case with T=const int*, which is *int const **, what you have with const T is:

```
int const * const
```

Which means a constant pointer to a constant int. Which is legal.

If it is not the desired behavior, you may have partial specialization, like:

```
template<typename T> struct A<const T>{
//here comes different implementation for the case where A template is
//initialized with a const type.
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not an issue to have multiple `const` qualifiers: they just fold together.

However you are misinterpreting it, because you are not placing it correctly (and it's a shame the syntax allows it).

If you place the `const` *after* the type it qualifies you'll realize that you were reading it wrong.

A `const T` where `T` is `const int*` is NOT `const const int* = const int*`.

If you write it correctly: `T const` where `T` is `int const*`, then you will read it `int const* const`, which is a `const` pointer to a `const` int, and NOT a pointer to a `const` int.

Answer (score 2):

[It's fine](http://ideone.com/3usIy) to do this

```
struct Foo {};
typedef const Foo CFoo;

const CFoo c;
```

Comment: It compiles doesn't mean it's legal.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers stand about constness, if you wanted the unqualified type, you can use a little template skull-duggery..

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_const
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_const<T*>
{
  typedef T* type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_const<const T>
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_const<const T*>
{
  typedef T* type;
};

template <typename T>
void foo (T& b)
{
  typename remove_const<T>::type a = b;
}
```

If you pass in a `const` pointer to `foo`, you'll see that `a` has the non-const type and therefore the assignment fails.

Answer (score 0):

`const int const *` is legal code and means a constant pointer to a constant value. Your code probably translates to the same expression.

Comment: No, this is wrong. What you have is a non-const pointer to const int (if your expression is legal).